What is the maximum number of admissible lines determined by $n$ points in the plane?
Let us say that a line in a plane is admissible if its slope equals 0,1,-1 or $\infty$. Problem 3.28 of "The Math Problems Notebook" (from Boju and Funar) is the following: What is the maximum number of admissible lines determined by $n$ points in the plane ?
Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be an $n$-point subset. Fixing a slope $m\in \{0,1,-1,\infty\}$, one can find at most $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ distinct lines of slope $m$ passing through pair of points of $S$ (indeed, each such line requires two points of $S$ and such $2$-sets (for distinct lines) are necessarily disjoint from one another). Therefore the number of admissible lines determined by $S$ is at most $4\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$. So if $n$ is even one finds the upper bounded $2n$ and if $n$ is odd one finds the upper bound $2n-2$. Given $n$, let us denote $f(n)$ the maximum number of admissible lines determined by $n$ points in the plane. In particular, it follows that for even $n$, $f(n)\leq 2n$ and for odd $n$, $f(n)\leq 2n-2$.
For $n\geq 3$ let $P_n$ be the image of the set of vertices of the regular $n$-gon (centered at the origin) to which one has applied the the affine map $(x,y)\mapsto (\sin (2\pi/n)x,\cos(2\pi/n)y)$. Note that this affine map preserves vertical and horizontal lines. In particular, when $n=8$, $P_8$ is the vertex set of the regular octogon.
(a) For $n\geq 8$ and $n\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ the bound $2n$ is attained with the configuration of points $P_n$ for example (there may be other configurations of $n$-points which attain this bound as well --- for example if $n=16$ one could take $P_{16}$ or two shifted copies of $P_8$, etc.). In particular for such $n$'s, $f(n)=2n$. Also, by adding one point $\{*\}$ to $P_n$ we also see that $P_n\cup\{*\}$ realizes the maximum for sets of $(n+1)$-points.
(b) When $n\geq 6$ and $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ the configuration $P_n$ admits $(2n-1)$ admissible lines. In particular this shows that for such $n$'s, $f(n)$ is either equal to $2n-1$ or to $2n$. The authors (Boju and Funar) claim that if $n\geq 14$ ($n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$), the bound $2n$ can be attained. However, after many trials, I was unable to find a configuration of 14 points with 28 lines but I could find a few ones with 27 lines.
Note that if $S_n$ were configuration of $n$-points with $2n$ admissible lines then
$S_n\cup\{*\}$ realizes the maximum for sets of $(n+1)$-points.
Q: Does there exist a set of 14 points with $28$ admissible lines ?
Remark As a side remark, starting with $P_{12}$ and modifying it a bit I was also able to construct a set of $15$ points which realizes the upper bound of $28$ admissible lines but it was connected (i.e. it did not come from a 14 point set with 28 lines to which one added an isolated point). Note that if for a given $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, $f(n)=2n$ then automatically $f(n+8k)=2(n+8k)$ (just keep adding suitably shifted copies of $P_8$). Similarly, if for some $n\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, $f(n)=2n-2$ then again $f(n+8k)=2(n+8k)-2$. In particular, it follows from (a) that for $n\geq 9$ and $n\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, that $f(n)=2n-2$. It seems to me that once one settles the case $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, then using what has been proved previously + induction should allows one to get all $n$'s. At that point, for $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and $n\geq 14$, I feel undecided about which one of the two values $2n-1$ or $2n$ is the correct one. From my rather limited empirical experiments I give more credence at that point to the value $2n-1$.
added (on the 10th of December): I had recently presented this problem during a Putnam practice session, a problem that I was unable to solve completely which explains the origin of this post. A few days ago, I contacted by email professor Louis Funar regarding that problem and, in his reply, he kindly acknowledged that "the sketch of proof" found in the book is indeed incomplete. Unfortunately he could not find (old) notes about his solution. He also tried to deal with the case $n=14$ without any success. So it seems to professor Funar and also to myself that the problem when $n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ (and $n\geq 14$) is non-trivial and interesting. My hunch tells me that there might be some "plane obstruction" in this case which prevents us from reaching the "trivial upper bound" $2n$, so that $f(n)$ would indeed be equal to $2n-1$, but I don't really see how to formulate this properly and even less how to prove it at this point in time.

This is explained in the first paragraph of the post.

@copper, the problem starts, "Let us say that a line in a plane is admissible if its slope equals $0,1,-1$ or $\infty$."

@GerryMyerson Never mind, I think I get it.

Note that for $P_{4k}$ (with k>=2), each vertex of the graph is "overworked" : we can't add a new admissible line using it, because it is already the meeting point of the maximum number of those. A new point on one of the admissible lines through this vertex will be aligned with two other points on the graph. It follows that adding new points to $P_{4k}$ is suboptimal, as you can't reuse the vertexes of $P_{4k}$. You arrive with $P_{4k}$ somewhere, and a group of points somewhere else, which can't support enough lines unless it contains more than 5 points.
But removing 1 vertex from $P_{4k}$ also removes 4 admissible lines, which creates a graph with $4k-1$ vertexes, and $2*4k-4 = 2(4k-2) = 2*(n-1)$ admissible lines, which is optimal (as $f(n) = 2(n-1)$ for odd numbers). This graph also has 4 free vertexes we can use to draw more admissible lines.
Let us then start with two copies of $P_8$ and remove one vertex from each. We get two copies of the optimal 7-vertex graph. This means we have 24 lines already drawn, and we only miss 4 to get the theoretical optimum. Through scaling and rotating one of the copies, I have managed to get the screenshot below ; the small octogon has scale 1/2, and the missing vertexes of each octogon are overlaid one above the other such that the 4 free vertexes are properly aligned. The missing vertexes were called F and Q ; lines QP and GF are overlaid in the result, as are lines FC and LQ, JQ and FA, and EF and NQ. The resulting lines are thus EN, PG, LC and JA, giving a 14-vertex graph with 28 lines


Dear @Cuagga, unless I missed something it seems to me that your construction works! That is a great idea to take these two shifted copies of $P_8$ where one is half the size of the other, and then "doing the construction backward" by deleting a pair of points which are juxtaposed! So in the end my hunch about the value of $f(14)$ to be $27$ was wrong!

@HugoChapdelaine, the idea I experimented with was not "taking two $P_8$, one half the size of the other". The answer is close to my actual thought process : iteratively adding vertexes to a $P_8$ doesn't work, let's experiment with removing vertexes to $P_8$. That seems close to optimal for 7. Can we double it and join them such that we overwork a maximum of our free vertexes ? Let's open Geogebra to check. It works, are there easy properties to describe it ? Yes : removed vertexes end up juxtaposed, side lengths are 1 and 1/2, and the centers are not on the same side of the removed vertex.

I find both your solution and thought process very elegant! I must confess that it did not occur to me of juxtaposing two removed vertices...
